I would like to get information about a specific Validator, including display name, and the total amount bounded
I would like to get information about a specific Validator, including display name, and the total amount bounded
I succeed to get the display name
const poolIdentity = await node.query.identity.identityOf(poolId);

But can't manage to get the total amount bonded to this validator including all stakers
How to do it ?
I saw this call
const stakers = await node.query.staking.erasStakersOverview(activeEra.unwrap().index, poolId);

But it returns nothing and in the documentation of these different calls it says that they are deprecated and we should use EraInfo instead. But what is EraInfo, I can't find it anywhere.
Thanks

This information is not found in one storage entry but divided among the storage entries of several pallets. Hence, my first suggestion is to use a block explorer or application specially designed to show all this information clearly and in one-click. For example, you can try:

The validators view of the Staking Dashboard
The validator view of Subscan block explorer.

If you are interested in knowing the relevant query on-chain to retrieve the total amount bonded to this validator, then you can try the Polkadot.js API query
const stakers = await node.query.staking.erasStakersPaged(eraNumber,Validator, pageNumb)
For example for validator 13XkGCa13arfw4FkH8MVsvshrHrA9GuKPANjZ7xnjKCSg9fM and era 1465 this returns:
[
  [
    [
      1,465
      13XkGCa13arfw4FkH8MVsvshrHrA9GuKPANjZ7xnjKCSg9fM
      0
    ]
    {
      pageTotal: 28,243,991,478,303,737
      others: [
        {
          who: 13X3GibMUQtmtQRbq1b2smt967MRViySc7vYEpeqJm9UEDYi
          value: 7,074,285,079,374
        }
        {
          who: 13Fv7btqKR2NQVZSaJAK1DhxKpxgjzE8twaWnwDk8B1u6voR
          value: 27,476,636,427,221,464
        }
        {
          who: 16MbsDpnL3WtpPGkF4peSi4zxVNqtJSLvDdjbCHAcSh6tvAo
          value: 760,280,766,002,899
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]

